# How to hide some feature based on the user login?

Tags: java, jsp, security, servlets, authorization

We would like to hide some code features based on user login in Tomcat. We are using the basic authentications. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check for user roles ( [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) ). Here is the related information from the official Java EE documentation: [What Is a Role?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html#bnbxp). And here is info related to Tomcat: [Realm Configuration HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**IF** what you meant was just hiding some resources depending on **whether the user is logged in or not** then it is just a matter of restricting access to some pages (see the references below).

**IF** you want to hide some feature based on the **who is logged in**, then one of the solutions is to check the user role right inside JSP and output the content accordingly.

Primitive example:
*sample.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('admin')}">
            <p>Content for admin.<p>
        </c:when>
        <c:when test=${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('someRole')}">
            <p>Some content here</p>
        <c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <p>Another Content</p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</body>
</html>
```

**NB!**
To be able to invoke methods with arguments using EL you must use minimum *Servlet version 3*.
Quote from here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

> Since EL 2.2, which is maintained as part of Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2
>   (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), it's possible to invoke
>   non-getter methods, if necessary with arguments.

---

**Another way to hide / restrict access to some of your pages depending on the user role** is to make security configurations in *web.xml*, or use annotations (minimum Java EE 5), or create your own **Filter** that checks the role of the user making request.

To create your own *Filter*, create a class that implements **[javax.servlet.Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/Filter.html)** interface and in the **[doFilter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html#doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain))** method check the role of the user that made a request by using HttpServletRequest method **[isUserInRole()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String))**.

Here is a simple example of implementing custom *Filter*:
*RoleCheckFilter.java*

```
package com.example.filter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class RoleCheckFilter.
 * Its purpose is to check logged-in user's role and
 * and accordingly allow or prevent access to the web resources.
 */
public class RoleCheckFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (request.isUserInRole("admin")) {
            // user have the appropriate rights, allow the request
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            // user does not have the appropriate rights, do something about it
            request.setAttribute("error", "You don't have enough rights to access this resource");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp");
            // or you could forward a user request somewhere
        }
    }


    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Add the appropriate filter configuration in *web.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    ...

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Role Check Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.example.filter.RoleCheckFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Role Check Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    ...

</web-app>
```

---

Of course **in your case**, considering the fact that you use *Basic Authentication*, it is much easier to make security configurations right in *web.xml* (**declarative security**) or use **programmatic security**.

Quote from the official Java EE documentation:

> Java EE security services can be implemented for web applications in
>   the following ways:
>
> - **Metadata annotations** (or simply, annotations) are used to specify information about security within a class file. When the application is deployed, this information can either be used by or overridden by the application deployment descriptor.
> - **Declarative security** expresses an application’s security structure, including security roles, access control, and authentication requirements in a deployment descriptor, which is external to the application.
>     Any values explicitly specified in the deployment descriptor override any values specified in annotations.
> - **Programmatic security** is embedded in an application and is used to    make security decisions. Programmatic security is useful when declarative security alone is not sufficient to express the security model of an application.

---

Check out official Java EE documentation related to securing Java EE applications (in your case pay attention to **Specifying an Authorization Constraint** part):
**[Java EE 6: Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html)**
**[Java EE 5: Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncas.html)**

Check out also examples from the official documentation:
**[Java EE 6. Examples: Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html)**
**[Java EE 5. Examples: Securing Web Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html)**